# Structure in differentials forms

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let $k \leq n$ and consider $\Omega^{k}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ the space of $k$-forms (smooth). Is this space a Banach space with any kind of suitable norm?

I can construct a family of semi-norms over a numerable covering of compact sets, but this is a Frechet space, not a Banach space.

Comment: Basically this space is just a finite sum of $\mathscr{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: I can construct a family of semi-norms over a numerable covering of compact sets, but this is a Frechet space, not a Banach space...

Comment: Any kind of suitable norm should respect this decomposition though. So it would make $\mathscr{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ a Banach as well. But then differentiation has unbounded eigenvalues so wouldn't be continuous...

Comment: You need compact domains to avoid the Frechet situation. If you have compactly supported forms, then perhaps you can think about it.